# Bad reflections on some faces in blender, good on substance painter

Tags: materials, texture-baking, normals

I've baked the high poly into low poly in substance, everything is right, and I can see perfectly the shading when it comes to the material I use in substance painter. But when I export those maps and textures to blender and use it in a material, I get this weird artifacts, like a bunch of faces are doing their own reflection... I don't exactly know what is happening.

In blender:
[image: Screenshot with error in blender]

In Substance painter:
[image]

(The substance one shows a little bit more than the blender one, just to be clear)

EDIT:

Here is the blend file, with the textures and all set. Also, as asked in the comments, I already tried to recalculate normal withtout luck, and the normal map I baked was with OpenGL, just to be sure. In the .blend file you can see there is a weird shading even in solid.

Also, Metallic, Roughness and Normal are all set as non-color space in the material.

[.blend with error](http://balmung.es/Katana_V2_with_error.blend)

Comment: Just to make sure, you have your normal, roughness, and metallic set to non-color space in blender, correct?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yup, all three in non-color, I use node wrangler to avoid forgetting those things xD I double checked anyways and yeah, all them as non-color

Comment: It looks like something weird with the normals, can you show what the blender version looks like with just diffuse and normals?

Comment: You can recalculate your object's outside reflection. Just go to the normal under the mesh then recalculate outside. or you can press Ctrl + N. Hope it helps buddy.

Comment: What kind of normal map did you export from Substance Open GL or Direct X?

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've uploaded the .blend with the resources. I've updated the main post to add info that you guys asked, too. Thanks!

Comment: @RobinBetts Nope, all textures are png 8 or 16 bits (normals are 16bits for example)

Comment: The corresponding part is clearly visible in the normal map itself. Can you try to save the texture in another format, .exr for instance?

Comment: @lemon I've tried 2 or 3 different formats, but all are the same. Seems like if it was the bake itself? shouldn't that show the same artifacts on substance?

Comment: Note that these faces are not planar (and it is not good). That's why you see that in solid mode.

Comment: @lemon Oh... so, that's maybe the problem? I saw two options in mesh -> clean up to make planar and such, but that options didn't do anything... How could I fix that?

Comment: more or less something like this, because that keep a loop along the edge: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMVi3.jpg

Comment: @lemon Indeed it looks better like that, but I tried something... and yeah, it was that! it's because that quads are non-planar. I tried only changing the direction of the tris those quads made, and... well, it's fixed now. I'm kinda new so I supposed that, as long as I don't have ngons, that wouldn't be much of a problem. Seems not! Gotta make an answer for if someone gets the same problem in the future. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems were caused by some non-planar quads as lemon said in the comments. For some reason, the direction in which tris are generated on those specific quads is important. Maybe in the bake, they were autogenerated in the opposite direction. I think that's the case, because when I join vertices to make edges in the opposite direction of the shading, all is fixed.

The topology could be better and include some edge loops on the sides, so the non-planar quads don't even exists at all, but well, for the moment, it works!

Some pictures to improve understanding of this kinda problem. This is the model in solid and render pre-fix:

[image: renderer pre-fix] [image: solid pre-fix]

And this is post-fix:

[image: renderer post-fix] [image: solid post-fix]

After that, I just re-baked the lowpoly, and worked like a charm. Thanks, everyone!